# Else block always running even if the if condition is true

Tags: linux, curl

I am writng a script in linux, where I am hitting one URL through curl command and if the response is "HTTP/1.1 200 OK", do nothing but if the response is anything other than 200 OK, I need to send a mail. Please find the script bellow and let me know why it is not working properly.

```
#!/bin/bash
status=$(curl -Is http://anyenv.com:9001/de/ | head -n 1)

match="HTTP/1.1 200 OK"

echo $status

echo $match

if [ "$status" = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" ]; then
        echo "System is in good health, no need to worry, stay happy." | mail -s "Tool Website is up and running!" any_mail@gmail.com

else

 mail -s "Tool website is down." any_mail@gmail.com < /home/myuser/mailbody.txt
fi;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the else block is running because the condition is not true.

Run

```
curl -Is http://anyenv.com:9001/de/ | head -n 1 | od -c
```

and you'll see that there is a carriage return character in the output ([because the protocol specifies it](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1.2)), which is missing from the `match` variable.

You can put it there with

```
match=$'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r'
```

Comment: matchVar=$"HTTP/1.1 200 OK"

Comment: removed CR from the end  and String is matching properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
if [[ "$status" =~ "200" ]]; then
......
```

Answer (score -1):

in your if use == instead of a single =

http://www.pyeung.com/pages/unix/linux/bashcomparisonoperators.html

Answer (score -1):

Use == operator instead of =

== checks whether value of $status=Http 200 OK
However if use =  it assigns the  value Http 200 OK to variable $status hence if else statement alwayz evaluate to be true
 If you still getting error use the below if statement
If [ $status == $match ]

Comment: if [[ "$statusCheck" ==  "$matchVar" ]]; then

Comment: guys, here the issue is that bash is not able to pick value of variables....if i am using syntax below...it is working fine...if [[ "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" ==  "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" ]]; then